# Sublime Text 2 Create template

Tags: editor

I want to build a project specific template to include in newly created PHP files same as Eclipse does as the following,

```
/**
 * @file test.theme.inc
 * DESCRIPTION LINE 1
 * DESCRIPTION LINE 2
 * DESCRIPTION LINE 3
 * @name test.theme.inc
 * @created Dec 21, 2012
 * @author Aneek
 * @version $Id:$
 * @copyright  
 * Proprietary and Confidential
 * Copyright (C) 2012 Company name. All Rights Reserved.
 */
```

How can I make such a template to use?

Comment: How is this related to TeX & friends?

Comment: I thought that I can add Editor related questions over in TeX. Anyway, my mistake...

Comment: SublimeFileTemplates comes to the help: https://github.com/mneuhaus/SublimeFileTemplates